# Django profile edit permission

Tags: python, django

I have a problem, I would like to make sure that only the logged-in judge or speaker can edit their own profile, I'm not quite sure if I should change it in templates or in view.
Thank you for all your advice, I'm new to all this

this is my update view for judges

```
@allowed_users(allowed_roles=['judges'])
def updateJudges(request, pk):
    judge = Judges.objects.get(id=pk)
    form = JudgesForm(instance=judge)

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = JudgesForm(request.POST, instance=judge)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('ksm_app:detail', judge.id)

    context = {'form':form}
    return render(request, 'ksm_app/judges_form.html', context)
```

and this is my update debatant view

```
def updateDebatants(request, pk):
    debatants = Debatants.objects.get(id=pk)
    form = DebatantsForm(instance=debatants)

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = DebatantsForm(request.POST, instance=debatants)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('ksm_app:debatants_detail', debatants.id)

    context = {'form':form}
    return render(request, 'ksm_app/debatants_form.html', context)
```

I just want to make that every user will see their profile but only one user can edit his own profile

Comment: How are `Judges` and `Debatants` linked to the `User`? Can you share the relevant parts of the models?

Answer (score 0):

If the `Debatants` and `Judges` model have a `ForeignKey` (or even better a `OneToOneField` to the user modell), you can make a view *without* a `pk` parameter, since this is specified by the user

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

def updateDebatants(request):
    debatants = get_object_or_404(Debatants, user=self.request.user)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = DebatantsForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=debatants)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('ksm_app:debatants_detail', debatants.id)
    else:
        form = DebatantsForm(instance=debatants)
    return render(request, 'ksm_app/debatants_form.html', {'form':form})
```

For the view for the `Judges` you can do in in a similar way.